# How can you send an html page with an image from a file via node.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am trying to send an html page with express from the node.js server but for some reason I cannot add an image that is a file
This is the code I tried:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.send(`<body><img src='test.png'></body>`)
});
```

Would appreciate help.

Comment: Firstly, in your snippet, you're terminating the string too early, use single quotes around the image path. Secondly, make sure `Content-Type` is set to `text/html`. You can do this with `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');`. Thirdly, you should probably be using a route instead of sending a response in your middleware (`app.get()` instead of `app.use()`).

Comment: I corrected the quotation marks, the problem was only in the writing here. I would appreciate further explanation on the rest

Comment: The second point is self-explanatory, just add that `res.set()` line before `res.send()`. On the third point, `app.use()` is used for middleware, as in it's something that is run after receiving a request but before sending a response, as a sort of "middleman". As far as I'm aware, you shouldn't be sending responses in middleware anyway. You probably want to use something like [`app,get()`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) instead.

Answer (score -1):

where should the code must look for the image?
it needs the relation address of the image in src property.
ex: '../../resources/img/test.png'